# mysql auto stripslashes when select contents from db?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, stripslashes

i'm in a strange situation, in my server when i insert string to DB with `mysql_real_escape_string` then i print it, everything is ok and looks like mysql make an auto stripslashes! for example i save `tes't` then print it: `tes't` but in my localhost with php 4.2 installed i give `tes\'t` with same code. whats mystery of mysql?? like to know how must insert and select data to db safe and clean, once forever! because it makes me really confuse!

Comment: PHP 4.2? Ouch. That is a full decade old and no longer supported. I would tell you to use PDO or MySQLi instead of the plain MySQL extension (so you could use prepared statements instead of escaping quotes), but you'd need PHP 5. You _really_ should upgrade if possible. :-)

Comment: ya its just for test and my laboratory ;-)

Comment: If I wanted to build a bird house, I _could_ use a crudely shaped club in place of a hammer, but why? lol

Comment: Even if it's just for testing, you shouldn't be using such an old version of PHP. Why test code with an outdated and deprecated language?

Comment: ok, you're right. i will change it.

Comment: so whats problem? php 4.2?? is mysql php performances changed since 4.2 to latest version?

Comment: The actual problem in this case is magic quotes, which was used in PHP 4 but was removed in recent PHP 5. But modern PHP 5 offers two better extensions for MySQL -- [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Both allow you to use prepared statements, which means you don't have to mess with escaping quotes. The regular old MySQL extensions you're using will eventually be removed. [Here's a comparison](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) of the three extensions for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have magic quotes turned on. Rather than trying to work around this, you should just turn it off. If you don't have access to the server, you should still deal with it in a global manner. For example:

```
if ( ( function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) || ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase') ) {
    foreach ( $_POST as $k => $v ) { $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v); }
    foreach ( $_GET as $k => $v ) { $_GET[$k] = stripslashes($v); }
    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $k => $v ) { $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v); }
}
```

Putting that at the beginning of your code makes sure magic quotes is dealt with on every occassion, meaning you won't have to keep track of where you have to deal with magic quotes.

More information in the notes here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Comment: i checked php info in local, its off but runtime is on, so problem is runtime??

Comment: That appears to be the case then, yes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php shows you an example of how you can disable that using the `set_magic_quotes_runtime` function.

Comment: one more question! whats natural mysql manner with php insert select data? my means it when i use `mysql_real_escape_string` mysql will stripslashe it auto? so i don't need to use stripslashes again when printing data?

Comment: Indeed, you won't have to use stripslashes anymore. Just using mysql_real_escape_string will be enough. Though to be honest, you shouldn't really be using the mysql_* functions anymore. PDO is definitely a lot better. If you're not that far though, just remember that you indeed won't have to use stripslashes anymore :)

Comment: if i will to use PDO all code structures must be change? or it's like mysql syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately it is quite a bit different. And at first probably quite a bit more confusing as well. However, once you are able to wrap your head around it, you'll see why it's better than using mysql_* ;) net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/ provides a great and simple starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It depends likely on PHP's magic quotes settings, more a PHP mystery than a MySQL mystery :) Instead of using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, you can use a more general function:

```
function escape($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $s=stripslashes($s);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}
```

With this code you check whether the option is active and performs a first stripping.

Comment: @Vahid let me know if it works this way, obviously you have to replace `mysql_real...()` with my `escape()` function :)

Comment: i tested your answer and using this method on server codes, but in my local server still getting a \ when print!